# Function to keep removing duplicates in a string. IndexError: string index out of range

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a function to keep removing duplicate characters in a string.

expect:
Input: "abbaca"
Output: "ca"

Input: "abbacabb"
Output: "ca"

Input: "aaabbaca"
Output: "ca"

I keep getting this error but can't figure out why:
IndexError: string index out of range

I've tried commenting out the case in which the duplicates are not at the end of the string and it worked.

This can excute but ignores all the duplicates at the beginning or in the middle:

```py
def fun(S):
    if len(S) < 2: return S
    keep = True
    while keep:
        for i in range(1, len(S)):
            keep = False
            #if S[i] == S[i - 1] and i < len(S) - 1:
                #S = S[:i-1] + S[i+1:]
                #keep = True
            if S[i] == S[i - 1] and i == len(S) - 1:
                S = S[:i-1]
                keep = True
    return S
```

This covers all cases but generates the error:

```py
def fun(S):
    if len(S) < 2: return S
    keep = True
    while keep:
        for i in range(1, len(S)):
            keep = False
            if S[i] == S[i - 1] and i < len(S) - 1:
                S = S[:i-1] + S[i+1:]
                keep = True
            if S[i] == S[i - 1] and i == len(S) - 1:
                S = S[:i-1]
                keep = True
    return S
```

Comment: Is `a` not duplicate  in your sample string? Why is the output `ca`?

Comment: The function keeps removing all the duplicates. For  "abbaca", it removes the "bb" first and the string becomes "aaca". "ca" is what left after duplicates "aa" are removed

Comment: It crashes because `for i in range(1, len(S))` iterates over the length of the original `S`, while in the algorithm you keep shortening it, so at some point you will be accessing an invalid index because the string is too short

Comment: `IndexError: string index out of range` means you are trying to access a character with an invalid index. For example, try running `"abcd"[4]`

Comment: Why would it execute after I commented out the cases that duplicates are in the middle or at the beginning, if removing the tail duplicates also shortens the string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not need an in-place algorithm:

```
def fun(s):
    stack = []
    for c in s:
        if len(stack) == 0 or stack[-1] != c:
            stack.append(c)
        else:
            stack.pop()
    return "".join(stack)
```

Output:

```
>>> fun('aabbcc')
''
>>> fun('abbacabb')
'ca'
>>> fun('abbaca')
'ca'
>>> fun('aaabbaca')
'ca'
```

Answer (score 2):

You could rewrite your solutions to avoid needing to deal with string indices.

If duplicates can only be occur twice (i.e. you could only have `aa`, not `aaa` for example), the following script will remove all duplicates:

```
ls = "aabcbbabbcc"
s = set(ls)

for ch in s:
    ls=ls.replace(ch+ch, ch)

print(ls)
```

If the `àaa` case is possible, then you would need to create a loop that continually executes the script above until no more duplicates are found, e.g:

```
ls = "aabcbbbbbaaabbcc"
s = set(ls)

current_length=len(ls)
duplicates=True
while duplicates:
    for ch in s:
        ls=ls.replace(ch+ch, ch)
    if len(ls)==current_length: #if length the same, then no duplicates have been found
        duplicates=False
    else:
        current_length = len(ls) #otherwise update the current length and continue


print(ls)
```

Comment: Good solution but it is possible that this person is doing some homework in which case they are probably not allowed to use python built-ins such as `replace` and they have to make the algorithm themselves

Comment: 'aaa' case is possible, the function has to remove the duplicates so I changed the alternative ch in the replace function to '', then it worked well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let's apply your algorithm to a simple case: `S = 'aabbcc'`. It would go like this (I'll go iterating over the values of `i` and evaluating many expressions):

```
i = 1
S = 'aabbcc'
if S[1]('a') == S[0]('a') and 1 < 6 - 1:
    S = S[:0]('a') + S[2:]('bbcc')
(I skip the if that are not executed)

i = 2
S = 'abbcc'
if S[2]('b') == S[1]('b') and 2 < 5 - 1:
    S = S[:1]('ab') + S[3:]('cc')

i = 3
S = 'abcc'
if S[3]('c') == S[2]('c') and 3 == 4 - 1:
    S = S[:2]('abc')

i = 4
S = 'abc'
if S[4](ERROR)...
```

As you can see, the algorithm doesn't stop when `i` is equal or bigger than `len(S)` being `S` the current string and not the initial one, so your algorithm throws an exception. You should calculate the number of iterations in some other way, probably using `while i < len(S)` or something like that.

Comment: Thank you for showing the steps, I get the point. But why would the partial codes execute if it would get out of the bound as well?

Answer (score 0):

> You can use **Python Recursion**
>
> Recursion is a way of programming or coding a problem, in which a
>   function calls itself one or more times in its body. Usually, it is
>   returning the return value of this function call. If a function
>   definition fulfils the condition of recursion, we call this function a
>   recursive function.
>
> A recursive function has to terminate to be used in a program. A
>   recursive function terminates, if with every recursive call the
>   solution of the problem is downsized and moves towards a base case. A
>   base case is a case, where the problem can be solved without further
>   recursion. A recursion can lead to an infinite loop, if the base case
>   is not met in the calls.

```
s = "aaabbaca"

def fun(s):
    for pos in range(1, len(s)):
        if s[pos] == s[pos-1]:
            s = s[:pos-1] + s[pos+1:]
            return fun(s)
    return s

print (fun(s))
```

output:

```
ca
```

Comment: I like the idea and it works but occupies too much resource when the original string is huge